# Is rtf syntax for bullet point correct?

Tags: html, rtf

I have to make an rtf to html converter. I have an already coded application but it has some bugs..
Whenever i enter a bullet point it crashes

**Original Rtf**

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0
>   Segoe UI;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset2 Symbol;}}
>   {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
>   \viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\lang3081\f0\fs18 Paragraph writing is the
>   foundation of all essay writing, whether the form is expository,
>   persuasive, narrative, or creative. In order to write a \ul\b\i good
>   paragraph\ulnone\b0\i0 . \par \lang1033  \par
>   \pard{\pntext\f2\''B7\tab}{*\pn\pnlvlblt\pnf2\pnindent0{\pntxtb\''B7}}\fi-165\li165
>   Element 1\cf0\f1\fs24  \par }

It crashes because of the line

> \pard{\pntext\f2\''B7\tab}{*\pn\pnlvlblt\pnf2\pnindent0{\pntxtb\''B7}}

If I remove this line the Rtf is converted to html successfully. I am new to Rtf syntax. So my question is...is this Rtf syntax correct in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RTF specification](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading46) shows that `\''` is not valid - `\'` should be followed by a hexadecimal value, but in your example it is followed by another apostrophe (and then by a hexadecimal value).

Comment: so the correct syntax was \par {\pntext1 \'B7\tab} line1  \par {\pntext1 \'B7\tab} line2